# I want class has predefined instances of its own - best way?

Tags: c#, serialization

For example, I have an Profile class with profile settings and want to provide several default profiles with according settings. **What is the best way to do it?**

I know some classes in .NET that have such functionality - like String with its static String.Empty property.

**1.** My current approach is

```
public static readonly ICollection<Profile> DefaultProfiles;
```

field inside Profile class. This field is filled with default profiles inside Profile's static constructor.

**2.** The bad case for this approach is serialization - serialization requires not static, not readonly members. So to serialize my Profile with default profiles I have to create special not static, not readonly property for it. But I also want the entities of Profile class have no new individual default profile list **before** serialization (of course it can't be after it). Can I reach it like this?

```
[Serializable]
public class Profile
{
    public static readonly ICollection<Profile> DefaultProfiles;        

    public List<Profile> DefaultProfilesToSerialize
    {
        get { return new List<Profile>(DefaultProfiles);; }
    }
}
```

So without any backing field for DefaultProfilesToSerialize there is only one instance of default profiles for each instance of Profile. Am I right?

Comment: This is a good approach, unless you are using a Database. Then i'd move the defaults there.

Comment: @lokusking, I add thoughts about serialization. My approach requires additional code to couple with serialization.

Comment: But do you *need* to serialize those predefined, unchanging default values? When someone uses one of those defaults, then it's just a regular value.

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, I do need. My clients have to receive predefined profiles. They also can create their own profiles. The full profile list on the client's side will be compilation of predefined and custom profiles.

Comment: You dont have to worry about serialization. since the defaults are stored as a constant in code, they will be always availiable

Comment: @lokusking I don't want to create default profile list for each Profile's entity. When couple with serialization I have to present my static readonly member as normal property - that will create list of profiles for each instance of Profile class, won't it?

Comment: You are right. This `ICollection<Profile>` will be in **every** instance of your object. You might consider to use a *Factory-Pattern* instead

Comment: @HansKesting Predefined profiles can be changed (I mean the properties of each predefined profile). Only the list of predefined profiles can't be changed.

Comment: I changed my question to make it more suitable for me.